# Python: I have 1000 x values and need corresponding y values

Tags: python, list, function, numpy, vector

I have this vector `x=np.linspace(0,100,1000)`, and a function:

```
(-1/(math.log(2)/5700))*math.log(x/100)
```

How can I calculate the corresponding `y` values and put them in a vector?

Comment: Did you try `numpy.log` instead of `math.log`?

Comment: I did that now, and it helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.log`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) instead of `math.log` for a vectorised approach, specially given that you're already using numpy:

```
y = (-1/(np.log(2)/5700))*np.log(x/100)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!